# How to use id/class from css into json block. The json block is used in JS code

Tags: javascript, html, css, json

I have not been able to use css class/id into json block. Can anyone help me in this case.

**css code:**

```
.colSmiles {
    background-color: #95D0EA;
    text-align: right;
    font-style: italic; 
}

.StandRelation {
    background-color: #A9A6A3;
    text-align: center;
}
```

**json block:**

```
var cellStyles = {
  "2" : {
    "type": "int",
    "defaultStyle": "background-color:white;font-size:10px;",
    "rule": [
      {
        "low"   : "lt",
        "value" : 0,
        "style" : "color:red;font-style:italic;"
      },
      {
        "low"   : "eq",
        "value" : 0,
        "style" : "font-size:20px;"
      },
      {
        "low"   : "gt",
        "value" : 0,
        "style" : "font-color:yellow;"
      }
    ]
  },
  "3" : {
    "type": "string",
    "defaultStyle": "",
    "rule": [
      {
        "low"   : "eq",
        "value" : "hoge",
        "style" : "font-color:white;background-color:red;"
      }
    ]
  }
};
```

**css from JSON are use here :**

```
function setCellStyle(coli, td, v){
  var cs = cellStyles[`${coli}`];
  if ('undefined' === typeof(cs) || null == cs) {
    return;
  }
  var ty = cs["type"];
  var ru = cs["rule"];
  var st = cs["defaultStyle"];
  if ('undefined' != typeof(ru) && null != ru) {
    ru.some(function(val, index){
      let op = logicalOperator[val["low"]];
      let rval = val["value"];
      if ("int" == ty) {
        if ('undefined' != op && null != op && eval(`${rval} ${op} ${v}`)) {
          st += val["style"];
          return true;
        }
      } else {
        if ('undefined' != op && null != op && eval(`"${rval}" ${op} "${v}"`)) {
          st += val["style"];
          return true;
        }
      }
    });
  }
  td.attr('style', st);
}
```

**st used here:**
td.attr('style', st);

I have created css class in separate css file and I want to use that css class inside the json block. How can I do that.

Comment: It is very unclear what you are trying to do. Please create a [mcve]

Comment: I just want to replace static css code with its css class in the place of "style" in json.

Comment: That still does not explain what you are doing with the JSON.

Comment: Actually, I am using this json in JS to change the css of the table. 
I am using this json as below in js. 
if ("int" == ty) {
            if ('undefined' != op && null != op && eval(`${rval} ${op} ${v}`)) {
              st += val["style"];
              return true;
            }
          } else {
            if ('undefined' != op && null != op && eval(`"${rval}" ${op} "${v}"`)) {
              st += val["style"];
              return true;
            }
          }
        });
      }`

Comment: question and its details has been updated.
thanks

Comment: So where is `st` used? You are not helping us much here - what is `ru`?

Comment: Also, that's not json thats a literal object notation

Comment: details updated. is this okay to understand.
And, "ru" is a rule from the JSON.